# Add onClickListener in a Map CustomView

Tags: android, maps, onclicklistener, android-custom-view, rx-java2

I created a Custom view to show a map in others fragments or activities.
But I want to get a simple click in frame, like google maps app does.
Anyone could help me?

There's custom view:

```
public class MapView extends FrameLayout {

  private Subject<GoogleMap> mapSubject;

  private static final float MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL_STATIC = 12.0f;

  private Circle mCircle;

  public MapView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
  }

  public MapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  public MapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,
             @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
  }

  private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =((AppCompatActivity)context)
        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.add(getId(), mapFragment);
      fragmentTransaction.commit();

      mapSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
      Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<GoogleMap>) e -> mapFragment.getMapAsync(e::onNext))
       .subscribe(mapSubject);
      mapSubject.subscribe(googleMap -> mCircle = googleMap.addCircle(new 
      CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(0.0f, 0.0f)).radius(0)));
    }
  }


  /**
   * Update position and create a new Circle and move camera to new position
   *
   * @param location The location to be updated.
   */
  public void updatePosition(LatLng location) {
    mapSubject.subscribe(googleMap -> {
      mCircle.remove();
      mCircle = googleMap.addCircle(new 
        CircleOptions().center(location).radius(15)
        .strokeWidth(10)
        .strokeColor(Color.RED)
        .fillColor(Color.RED));

      googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 
        MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL_STATIC));
      });
  }

  /**
   * This method is responsible to add a polyline in google maps
   *
   * @param results array with directions
   */
  public void addPolyline(DirectionsResult results) {
    if(results != null) {
      mapSubject.subscribe(googleMap -> {
        List<LatLng> decodedPath = 
          PolyUtil.decode(results.routes[0]
          .overviewPolyline
          .getEncodedPath());

        googleMap.addPolyline(new 
          PolylineOptions()
            .addAll(decodedPath)
            .width(10)
            .color(Color.RED)
            .geodesic(true));

        updatePosition(decodedPath.get(0));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

That's how I use in xml:

```
<com.name.of.package.custom_view.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Thats how I'm trying to identify click (without success, because in debugger didn't pass here):

```
MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView)
mapView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    toogle(view);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Map clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching about, I find a way to verify simple click in maps.

Create an function in MapView.java

```
/**
* This method is responsible to add a MapClickListener to handle simple clicks in map.
*
* @param mapClickListener class that will handle simple click
*/
public void setOnMapClick(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener mapClickListener) {
  mapSubject.subscribe(googleMap -> googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(mapClickListener));
}
```

After that, set an listener when you use mapView, for example:

```
mapView.setOnMapClick(this);
```

PS.: To put `this` you need to implement `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener` in you activity/fragment that you are using mapView.

After implement, put override method in your fragment/activity:

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
  if (Logger.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick");
  // Do something
}
```